# Google Adword API: How to get total spent amount for given account using CURL/SOAP

Tags: php, curl, soap, google-ads-api

**As I want how much amount have spent on that account for ads by using the google adword api**. I need to integrate that code in PHP.

If any one has any idea, please share with me. I have already search a lot but not get the what I have expected.

My question is to get the total spent on given account by using the **adword api**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total spent by time period using any one of several reports in the AdWords API.

If you're just after the totals for each account, the [account performance report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/account-performance-report) is probably the right one. You can only get reports for one account at a time - there is no consolidated report for multiple accounts.

I've written a high-level overview of using the AdWords API to automate bits of AdWords [here](https://pete-bowen.com/how-to-use-the-google-adwords-api-to-automate-adwords).

Comment: thanks for reply @Peter. As u said "You can get the total spent by time period using any one of several reports in the AdWords API" can u plz tell which one is better?

Comment: Hi @Peter, Can you please help out as I have some doubts. I need steps that How to integrate Adword API with our PHP code to prepare the various reports?